# OSError: [Errno 27] File too large idk why

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
n=input()
count=1
while count != int(n):
    if count%3==0:
        print('Fizz')
        continue
    elif count%5==0:
        print('Buzz')
        continue
    elif count % 3==0 and count % 5==0:
        print('FizzBuzz')
        continue
    else:
        print(count)
    count+=1
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong

I've tried to change the condition to end the loop to  `while count > int(n):` but it is still not working

it always gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 5, in <module>
    print('Fizz')
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
```

Comment: if any `if` or `elif` block is executed `count` is not getting incremented. Which in turn can lead to infinite loop. Remove the `continue` statements

Comment: you have infinite while loop that keeps on writing to stdout and fails after a while

Comment: This code in isolation does no such thing. If you are running it with output to a file, please show us that (and probably indicate which platform you are on; I'm vaguely guessing this is the usual Windows nonsense).

Comment: Please post your command line, your input and your expected and actual output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't increment `count`, so it writes to stdout a lot of copies of the same line.

```
n=input()
count=1
while count != int(n):
    if count%3 == 0 and count%5 == 0:
        print('FizzBuzz')
    elif count%5 == 0:
        print('Buzz')
    elif count%3 == 0:
        print('Fizz')
    else:
        print(count)
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. iteration: Your code starts with `count = 1`. All `if` conditions are `False`, so `count` is incremented by 1.
2. iteration: `count` has a value of 2. All conditions are `False` again, so `count` is incremented again.
3. iteration: `count` has a value of 3, so the first condition is `True`. The `continue` keyword makes the `while` loop directly continue with the next iteration, and skips the incrementing of `count`.

After that, the behaviour of the 3rd iteration is repeated - you have created an endless loop, because, as the `if` condition is always `True`, the `while` loop always skips the incrementation of `count`. The easy fix for this problem would be to delete all occurrences of `continue` in your code. This should get rid of the `OSError: File too large` too.